# Is it possible to run e2e tests in different google kubernetes engine clusters?

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, automated-tests, google-kubernetes-engine, spinnaker

I have two private GKE clusters: the first with jenkins, and the second with an app to be tested. The problem is that jenkins can not communicate with the app in the second cluster.

Making a direct connection between these clusters is not allowed. Unfortunately, installing jenkins in a cluster with the app is not allowed. Spinnaker has access to all clusters, so we started to use spinnaker to run our containerized tests. In some ways it works, but there is a problem with gathering test results or retrying the tests. Also the whole setup for doing this is very complex.

I am looking for simpler solution, maybe there is a way to run tests on a second cluster using jenkins? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running e2e tests using Spinnaker is a tricky task.

We have standby Jenkins in the same cluster as Spinnaker which have the same network rules, so such Jenkins has connection to the same clusters/namespaces/resources as Spinnaker does.